# Conditional probabilities in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction with the following data I have.

A snap shot of the data looks like the following;

```
    PANID       WEEK brandID mariedstatus educ_male_HH educ_fem_HH
1 1100016 2001-03-19      48            2            2           3
2 1100016 2001-07-30      48            2            2           3
3 1100016 2001-12-17      48            2            2           3
4 1100057 2001-06-11     209            2            5           6
5 1100057 2001-06-18     207            2            5           6
6 1100057 2001-06-18     217            2            5           6
```

So I have data on people (`PANID`), the `WEEK` that they bought a particular brand and the `brandID`. Then some demographics, marital status, male household education, female household education etc.

I am trying to calculate conditional probabilities, so given the fact that `PANID` bought `brandID` number `48` on `WEEK` - `2001-03-19` what is the probability, they will buy the same brand again.

So I am just looking for some advice / code on how I can go about solving this issue.

I have thought about creating a binary variable to determine whether a person has bought the same brand more than once during the year

```
  df %>%
  group_by(PANID, brandID) %>%
  mutate(user_total_brand_purchases = n()) %>%
  mutate(reordered = ifelse(user_total_brand_purchases > 1, 1, 0))
```

But I am not sure that this solves my issue.

Sample of data:

```
     df <- structure(list(PANID = c(1100016L, 1100016L, 1100016L, 1100057L, 
1100057L, 1100057L, 1100057L, 1100057L, 1100057L, 1100057L, 1100057L, 
1100180L, 1100180L, 1100321L, 1100404L, 1100404L, 1100545L, 1100560L, 
1100560L, 1101162L, 1101162L, 1101238L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 
1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 
1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 
1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 
1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 
1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101279L, 1101758L, 1102012L, 
1102046L, 1102384L, 1102384L, 1103069L, 1103101L, 1103101L, 1103101L, 
1103101L, 1103101L, 1103101L, 1103101L, 1103325L, 1103614L, 1103671L, 
1103671L, 1103895L, 1103895L, 1103895L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 
1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 1104182L, 
1104182L, 1104182L, 1104208L, 1104208L, 1104224L, 1104273L, 1104315L, 
1104315L, 1104315L, 1104315L, 1104364L, 1104372L, 1104372L, 1104406L, 
1104869L, 1104968L, 1105171L, 1105171L, 1105239L, 1105239L, 1105239L, 
1105965L, 1105999L, 1106146L, 1106567L, 1106567L, 1106567L, 1106575L, 
1107235L, 1107235L, 1107235L, 1107235L, 1107235L, 1107235L, 1107235L, 
1107425L, 1107425L, 1107581L, 1107581L, 1107847L, 1107847L, 1107862L, 
1107953L, 1108043L, 1108225L, 1108308L, 1108308L, 1108308L, 1108308L, 
1108308L, 1108308L, 1108308L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 
1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 
1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1108456L, 1109165L, 1109165L, 
1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 
1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 1109306L, 
1109306L, 1109306L, 1109447L, 1109447L, 1109447L, 1109470L, 1109470L, 
1109470L, 1109470L, 1109470L, 1109470L, 1109470L, 1109488L, 1109595L, 
1109629L, 1109629L, 1109629L, 1109629L, 1109629L, 1109629L, 1109629L, 
1109629L, 1109629L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 
1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 
1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 
1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 1109652L, 
1109652L, 1109769L, 1109769L, 1109769L, 1109769L, 1109769L, 1109835L, 
1109835L, 1109835L, 1109835L, 1109835L, 1109835L, 1109868L, 1109868L, 
1109892L, 1109892L, 1109892L, 1109892L, 1110072L, 1110072L, 1110072L, 
1110072L, 1110072L, 1110403L, 1110403L, 1110403L, 1110403L, 1110403L, 
1110403L, 1110403L, 1110437L, 1110445L, 1110445L, 1110445L, 1110445L, 
1110445L, 1110445L, 1110650L, 1110759L, 1110833L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 
1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 
1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 1110908L, 
1110908L, 1110940L, 1110940L, 1111138L, 1111138L, 1111187L, 1111229L, 
1111245L, 1111245L, 1111245L, 1111245L, 1111245L, 1111245L, 1111450L, 
1111450L, 1111450L, 1111526L, 1111526L, 1111526L, 1111526L, 1111542L, 
1111542L, 1111559L, 1111617L, 1111971L, 1112052L, 1112052L, 1112052L, 
1112110L, 1112235L, 1112235L, 1112235L, 1112235L, 1112235L, 1112235L, 
1112805L, 1112805L, 1112920L, 1113142L, 1113225L, 1113225L, 1113225L, 
1113225L, 1113225L, 1113282L, 1113282L, 1113282L, 1113282L, 1113282L, 
1113589L, 1113589L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 
1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 1113746L, 
1113886L, 1113902L, 1113902L, 1113902L, 1113902L, 1113902L, 1113902L, 
1114413L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 
1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 
1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 1114421L, 
1114710L, 1114983L, 1114983L, 1114983L, 1114983L, 1114983L, 1114983L, 
1115154L, 1115154L, 1115154L, 1115378L, 1115808L, 1116210L, 1116467L, 
1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 
1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 
1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116467L, 1116657L, 1116681L, 
1116681L, 1116681L, 1116681L, 1116681L, 1116699L, 1116699L, 1116699L, 
1116798L, 1116798L, 1116798L, 1117127L, 1117127L, 1117259L, 1117259L, 
1117259L, 1117259L, 1117267L, 1117572L, 1117572L, 1117572L, 1117614L, 
1117614L, 1117747L, 1117846L, 1118356L, 1118356L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 
1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 
1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 
1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118430L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 
1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 
1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118588L, 1118976L, 
1119008L, 1119008L, 1119008L, 1119008L, 1119008L, 1119008L, 1119008L, 
1119008L, 1119057L, 1119057L, 1119057L, 1119115L, 1119115L, 1119115L, 
1119214L, 1119610L, 1119743L, 1119743L, 1119743L, 1119743L, 1119743L, 
1119784L, 1119784L, 1119784L, 1119909L, 1120600L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 
1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 
1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120618L, 1120725L, 1120782L, 1121004L, 
1121004L, 1121723L, 1121723L, 1121723L, 1121723L, 1121723L, 1121723L, 
1121723L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 
1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 1121749L, 
1121962L, 1121962L, 1121962L, 1121962L, 1122226L, 1122325L, 1122325L, 
1122325L, 1122325L, 1122325L, 1122572L, 1122572L, 1122572L, 1122713L, 
1122713L, 1122713L, 1122747L, 1122747L, 1122747L, 1122747L, 1122747L, 
1122754L, 1122762L, 1122861L, 1122861L, 1122861L, 1123430L, 1123448L, 
1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 
1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 
1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 
1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123448L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 
1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 1123489L, 
1123489L, 1123489L, 1123810L, 1123810L, 1123810L, 1124024L, 1124024L, 
1124024L), WEEK = structure(c(11400, 11533, 11673, 11484, 11491, 
11491, 11519, 11561, 11568, 11582, 11603, 11344, 11351, 11673, 
11673, 11673, 11533, 11344, 11631, 11442, 11652, 11673, 11323, 
11323, 11344, 11344, 11344, 11372, 11372, 11372, 11393, 11400, 
11400, 11414, 11414, 11428, 11428, 11435, 11435, 11449, 11470, 
11470, 11470, 11526, 11526, 11533, 11533, 11547, 11561, 11568, 
11568, 11568, 11589, 11589, 11610, 11610, 11631, 11652, 11421, 
11463, 11449, 11680, 11680, 11659, 11323, 11351, 11379, 11540, 
11610, 11645, 11659, 11645, 11442, 11498, 11540, 11519, 11540, 
11596, 11337, 11407, 11435, 11456, 11470, 11491, 11526, 11561, 
11589, 11596, 11666, 11666, 11519, 11540, 11554, 11414, 11673, 
11673, 11673, 11673, 11673, 11442, 11673, 11673, 11386, 11673, 
11540, 11673, 11484, 11491, 11596, 11680, 11673, 11505, 11323, 
11344, 11554, 11610, 11463, 11463, 11484, 11498, 11498, 11645, 
11659, 11379, 11484, 11533, 11673, 11414, 11428, 11533, 11631, 
11680, 11547, 11344, 11344, 11344, 11344, 11372, 11442, 11561, 
11372, 11379, 11393, 11421, 11442, 11456, 11463, 11498, 11498, 
11554, 11554, 11575, 11582, 11596, 11610, 11673, 11575, 11666, 
11428, 11449, 11463, 11477, 11498, 11512, 11526, 11540, 11554, 
11561, 11575, 11575, 11589, 11624, 11638, 11666, 11463, 11519, 
11589, 11351, 11365, 11400, 11547, 11547, 11617, 11645, 11498, 
11547, 11337, 11344, 11372, 11414, 11463, 11484, 11498, 11505, 
11673, 11337, 11351, 11358, 11365, 11393, 11400, 11407, 11407, 
11414, 11421, 11449, 11456, 11463, 11463, 11498, 11505, 11519, 
11519, 11526, 11533, 11547, 11568, 11575, 11589, 11617, 11659, 
11666, 11323, 11379, 11484, 11631, 11638, 11540, 11575, 11610, 
11617, 11631, 11659, 11449, 11589, 11519, 11519, 11673, 11673, 
11421, 11582, 11582, 11596, 11666, 11330, 11351, 11379, 11477, 
11526, 11582, 11610, 11442, 11379, 11379, 11477, 11540, 11561, 
11624, 11596, 11505, 11645, 11351, 11358, 11372, 11379, 11400, 
11407, 11421, 11484, 11512, 11526, 11533, 11554, 11561, 11568, 
11631, 11652, 11666, 11519, 11610, 11358, 11379, 11554, 11456, 
11407, 11428, 11470, 11533, 11631, 11673, 11526, 11589, 11603, 
11442, 11498, 11554, 11638, 11505, 11575, 11547, 11519, 11323, 
11477, 11526, 11547, 11673, 11456, 11463, 11463, 11589, 11645, 
11645, 11365, 11498, 11561, 11596, 11519, 11526, 11554, 11624, 
11638, 11505, 11512, 11519, 11568, 11589, 11379, 11540, 11344, 
11407, 11449, 11463, 11477, 11491, 11491, 11505, 11505, 11533, 
11596, 11680, 11554, 11449, 11540, 11568, 11568, 11575, 11673, 
11554, 11351, 11358, 11379, 11407, 11407, 11407, 11428, 11428, 
11435, 11442, 11456, 11470, 11477, 11498, 11505, 11512, 11526, 
11561, 11561, 11610, 11365, 11358, 11449, 11498, 11533, 11540, 
11582, 11344, 11673, 11673, 11575, 11659, 11386, 11379, 11386, 
11393, 11407, 11421, 11498, 11540, 11540, 11547, 11561, 11568, 
11568, 11589, 11603, 11610, 11617, 11631, 11645, 11666, 11666, 
11638, 11512, 11540, 11561, 11582, 11596, 11484, 11498, 11533, 
11344, 11680, 11680, 11358, 11477, 11400, 11561, 11582, 11603, 
11428, 11645, 11645, 11673, 11526, 11638, 11337, 11533, 11365, 
11673, 11358, 11372, 11386, 11407, 11435, 11463, 11477, 11484, 
11505, 11526, 11540, 11554, 11554, 11575, 11589, 11603, 11610, 
11631, 11638, 11652, 11666, 11351, 11414, 11421, 11435, 11449, 
11456, 11477, 11540, 11561, 11596, 11631, 11631, 11659, 11666, 
11673, 11645, 11442, 11463, 11477, 11575, 11589, 11596, 11624, 
11652, 11442, 11533, 11554, 11407, 11407, 11435, 11491, 11673, 
11407, 11477, 11547, 11547, 11680, 11484, 11596, 11659, 11638, 
11519, 11330, 11344, 11365, 11365, 11407, 11428, 11491, 11491, 
11505, 11540, 11554, 11561, 11561, 11568, 11568, 11414, 11610, 
11351, 11484, 11484, 11484, 11484, 11533, 11652, 11477, 11491, 
11498, 11512, 11512, 11533, 11540, 11540, 11540, 11547, 11547, 
11582, 11596, 11393, 11540, 11645, 11673, 11673, 11526, 11526, 
11582, 11603, 11666, 11547, 11547, 11645, 11589, 11589, 11589, 
11421, 11582, 11582, 11680, 11680, 11645, 11526, 11365, 11393, 
11659, 11638, 11330, 11337, 11344, 11358, 11365, 11400, 11407, 
11414, 11512, 11519, 11533, 11547, 11547, 11582, 11596, 11610, 
11617, 11624, 11638, 11645, 11645, 11666, 11673, 11673, 11673, 
11680, 11414, 11442, 11456, 11505, 11519, 11533, 11575, 11603, 
11631, 11638, 11652, 11659, 11512, 11533, 11533, 11323, 11463, 
11589), class = "Date"), brandID = c(48, 48, 48, 209, 207, 217, 
29, 29, 90, 90, 90, 131, 215, 28, 50, 208, 136, 216, 207, 48, 
48, 28, 29, 28, 29, 28, 140, 29, 28, 140, 29, 28, 140, 29, 28, 
29, 28, 29, 28, 28, 29, 28, 140, 29, 28, 28, 140, 33, 28, 29, 
28, 140, 29, 28, 28, 140, 28, 28, 131, 140, 29, 209, 214, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 153, 153, 153, 153, 29, 53, 28, 33, 135, 135, 209, 
211, 128, 225, 211, 211, 62, 211, 156, 62, 211, 211, 62, 217, 
217, 32, 50, 209, 210, 211, 156, 214, 48, 48, 48, 50, 173, 138, 
140, 207, 217, 214, 127, 69, 29, 100, 100, 214, 48, 51, 50, 51, 
131, 51, 51, 51, 230, 246, 32, 32, 50, 50, 28, 100, 131, 135, 
82, 1, 6, 69, 82, 7, 1, 48, 48, 79, 48, 48, 29, 29, 29, 48, 79, 
48, 29, 173, 29, 29, 29, 173, 99, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 
140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 250, 28, 131, 
34, 158, 34, 34, 157, 157, 157, 48, 50, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 50, 99, 50, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 230, 230, 230, 135, 135, 230, 228, 138, 207, 135, 
250, 209, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 140, 
29, 29, 136, 136, 29, 29, 131, 48, 206, 131, 131, 28, 29, 131, 
131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 48, 29, 131, 127, 250, 
250, 48, 48, 50, 157, 56, 147, 56, 100, 56, 56, 28, 147, 147, 
46, 209, 209, 29, 230, 127, 69, 29, 28, 28, 28, 50, 131, 209, 
79, 25, 209, 82, 209, 99, 230, 127, 197, 82, 1, 82, 82, 131, 
43, 43, 26, 131, 49, 28, 28, 29, 202, 127, 127, 127, 127, 135, 
29, 127, 127, 202, 127, 100, 153, 157, 48, 214, 48, 48, 131, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 140, 29, 50, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 28, 29, 50, 29, 140, 117, 217, 48, 48, 28, 171, 117, 6, 214, 
28, 51, 195, 225, 70, 125, 80, 246, 207, 127, 131, 207, 131, 
127, 147, 209, 209, 214, 214, 1, 80, 209, 209, 209, 158, 48, 
228, 158, 228, 131, 48, 131, 50, 50, 7, 230, 127, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 140, 131, 214, 214, 135, 135, 127, 28, 230, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 28, 158, 28, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 28, 48, 
48, 28, 48, 69, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 209, 50, 50, 209, 214, 214, 
69, 69, 69, 48, 138, 138, 138, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 48, 100, 
100, 157, 28, 209, 230, 148, 123, 29, 29, 230, 157, 209, 209, 
50, 53, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 131, 131, 131, 131, 
48, 28, 131, 140, 29, 209, 29, 140, 202, 69, 29, 209, 135, 135, 
230, 28, 230, 61, 138, 230, 135, 48, 50, 48, 61, 140, 131, 127, 
28, 63, 52, 217, 56, 209, 50, 140, 135, 48, 28, 140, 135, 50, 
101, 101, 224, 50, 131, 217, 140, 140, 140, 77, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
28, 29, 29, 29, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 28, 140, 28, 48, 
48, 140, 48, 97, 127, 131, 29, 29, 29), mariedstatus = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L), educ_male_HH = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 4L, 4L, 4L), educ_fem_HH = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
8L)), row.names = c(NA, 600L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

`PANID: 1100057` for example bought the same brand on the `09-03` and then again two weeks later on the `09-17` and then 3 weeks later on the `10-08`.

```
    PANID       WEEK brandID mariedstatus educ_male_HH educ_fem_HH
1 1100057 2001-06-11     209            2            5           6
2 1100057 2001-06-18     207            2            5           6
3 1100057 2001-06-18     217            2            5           6
4 1100057 2001-07-16      29            2            5           6
5 1100057 2001-08-27      29            2            5           6
6 1100057 2001-09-03      90            2            5           6
7 1100057 2001-09-17      90            2            5           6
8 1100057 2001-10-08      90            2            5           6
```

Comment: you need to specify minimal reproducible example with values that you expect to get. otherwise it is impossible to say wether it solves your problem

Comment: I think first you need to define a timeframe in which we would like to know the probability they buy the product again. Given that timeframe and sizeable data I would identify similar individuals to the one in question and and check how many of them bought the product twice or more in the defined timeframe and use the proportion to estimate the probability. Maybe this question will be better received at cross validated

Comment: Thanks for both your replies. The time frame would be whether they would buy the same brand within a month. (I will update my original post to make it more clear).

Comment: Can you expand upon how you would locate similar individuals? group them by similar brand purchases and demographic information?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use logistic regression to fit a model and predict on the event "buy more than once a brand" conditional on demographics, week, and brandID

```
# Package
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

## Data

# df unique customer
df_panid <- data %>%
  select(-WEEK, -brandID) %>%
  unique()

# df brand
df_brand_buy <- data %>%
  group_by(PANID, brandID) %>%
  # number times PANID buy each brand same brand
  # week of first buy
  summarise(n_same = n(),
            WEEK = min(week(WEEK))) %>%
  # dummy variable buy more than once
  mutate(buy_same = ifelse(n_same > 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  right_join(df_panid, by = "PANID") %>%
  # factor
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-PANID), as.factor)

# Logistic regression
fit <- glm(buy_same ~ WEEK + brandID + mariedstatus + educ_male_HH + educ_fem_HH,
             data = df_brand_buy,
             family = binomial
           )

# Probs
predict.glm(fit,
            newdata = data_frame(WEEK = factor(week(date("2001-03-19"))),
                                 brandID = factor(48),
                                 mariedstatus = factor(2),
                                 educ_male_HH = factor(2),
                                 educ_fem_HH = factor(3)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this input. A simple logistic regression seems perfect at this stage. When I run the code on the data the `predict.glm()` returns `21.56607` what does this mean? I understand the regression output but not so sure on the predict glm.

Comment: Yes, it could be a simple solution. To have the prob to buy again **in the year** conditionaly to the **month** change by `summarise(n_same = n(),
            month = min(month(WEEK)))` in the "df_brand_buy" construction, and add the argument `type = "response"`in the `predict.glm` function